# Why can't I attach an action to the new Sign In With Apple ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton in a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, ios13

I'm working on a new codebase that has everything laid out in storyboards and I'm trying to implement the new ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton button as part of the new Sign In With Apple feature.

Reading online it looks like I can add a UIButton to the view and then override the class to be ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton. Easy enough. The weird parts comes when I try and wire that button up to an action in the VC. I can't do it. Even if I go the other way and drag from the button to the VC, the action item is missing from the connection menu.

Has anyone had success adding and interacting with this button from a storyboard? I'd prefer not to redo the entire view just because of this one issue.

Comment: None so far. Had to insert the ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton manually into my stack view. Since it inherits from UIControl and not from UIButton directly, could it be the issue ? Kind of a shame that ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton isn't directly available in the Storyboard Editor.

Answer (score 0):

`ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` is **not a button but its a control**. And this is stated in that way to avoid misuse of this as a button. And only one action is associated with it which cannot be override. The only control you get is to use the delegate method of

`didCompleteWithAuthorization` & `didCompleteWithError`.

**`So if you want to use/include some extra selector or methods. you can add those in these delegate- methods.`**